# How to display ACF Front end form with only selected fields from field group?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I want to display ACF form in the front end. Also form with only selected fields from field group is requirement. I am new in WordPress can you please elaborate process of the display form in the front end. ? Also, make design of ACF form so how I pass HTML in act form

Answer (score 1):

The [acf_form()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf_form/) function accepts an array of options. You can set specific field groups or fields by passing in an array of field IDs/Keys. You can also add HTML before and after the form's fields.

```
$options = array(
    'field_groups' => array(),
    'fields' => => array(),
    'html_before_fields' => '',
    'html_after_fields' => '',
);

acf_form( $options );
```

You can see an overview of how to [create a front end form](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/create-a-front-end-form/).

Answer (score -1):

I recently have done with that same task. need to work with wordpress own api from the scratch. I have referred to below link, and very helpful to me.

https://wpshout.com/wordpress-submit-posts-from-frontend/

After above, you will need ajax function with validate.

I use validate form, https://jqueryvalidation.org with a basic ajax script.